# Uber menu on mobile not opening after Woodmart theme 7.4.2 update

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, menu

After Woodmart theme update to v7.4.2 Uber Menu on mobile will not open when clicked. I figure it is due to Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - jQuery. Please help!

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Uber menu on mobile can´t open

[image]

After Woodmart theme update mobile menu can´t open.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.